# How to separate submit button and checkboxes in php

Tags: php

I know this code will not work but can anyone teach me what can I do.

```
<table> 
<tr>
<form method ="post" action ="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<th>Stock</th><th>Value</th><th><input type = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></th>

</tr>

<?php
while($grow = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlqueresult)) :
    $gsymbol = $grow['symbol'];
    $gclose = $grow['value'];
?>
    <tr>
    <td style='width: 100px;'><?php echo "$gsymbol"?></td>
    <td><?php echo "$gclose"?></td>
    <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "arrsymbols[]" value = '".$gsymbol."'></td>
    </tr>
</form>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
```

How to make this code works? Or how should I include the submit and checkbox in one form that between them is a while statement

Comment: first of all your code is written in wrong way because you include the end of the form with in a while loop

Comment: the second error you have is the name of checkbox you use arrsymbols[] which is a way to add values to array not to display value

Comment: Do you need to have separate forms for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Thanks Osama will look for how to display value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there were few issues in your code. Please try the below code,

```
<form method ="post" action ="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <table> 
  <tr>
     <th>Stock</th>
     <th>Value</th>
     <th><input type = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></th>
  </tr>
  <?php
    while($grow = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlqueresult)) : ?>
      <tr>
         <td style='width: 100px;'><?php echo $grow['symbol']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $grow['value']; ?></td>
         <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "arrsymbols[]" value = "<?php echo $grow['symbol']; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  <tr>
 <table>
 </form>
<?php
```

Comment: This code works. Thanks man. whats the purpose of another submit button after endwhile?

Comment: Just thought it would be good to have the submit button at the bottom. Please remove if not required

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your code.

```
  <?php 


while($grow = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlqueresult)) {
    $gsymbol = $grow['symbol'];
    $gclose = $grow['value'];
?>
    <tr>
    <td style='width: 100px;'><?php echo $gsymbol; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $gclose; ?></td>
    <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "arrsymbols[]" value ="<?php echo $gsymbol; ?> " ></td>
    </tr>
<?php   } ?>    

</form>
```

Comment: you don't end the input tag